# v.kernel is missing under Processing Toolbox GRASS GIS 7 commands

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, windows-7

I installed the QGIS Standalone Installer Version 2.14 (64bit), that automatically contains GRASS 7.0.4. I created a map with several layers and rasters in the program called QGIS Desktop 2.14.3 with GRASS 7.0.4.

I need one tool from Processing -> Toolbox -> GRASS GIS 7 commands -> Vector -> **v.kernel** => but is missing there. All the other vectors (v.XY) work well. Because I found v.kernel under GRASS commands, I activated it in the Processing options.

Under GRASS commands -> Vector -> v.kernel appears but is not working, none of the vectors (v.XY) is :

[image]

When I click on Enable additional providers at the bottom of the Processing Toolbox I see the Processing options :

[image]

The path for the GRASS7 folder is right. I put the same for the GRASS folder. But I cannot found the Msys folder in whole PC.

When i check Plugins -> Manage and Install Plugins -> GRASS7 is installed.

When I go to XY\QGIS Essen\apps\grass\grass-7.0.4\bin, I can see v.kernel.

Did anyone face the same problem?

Basically I have two questions:

1) Why v.kernel is not under GRASS GIS 7 commands? And how can I have it?

2) Why v.kernel and all the other vectors (v.XY) under GRASS commands are not working?

Answer (score 3):

In GRASS GIS 7, there are two v.kernel tools: v.kernel.rast and v.kernel.vector. These tools are available in the current development version of QGIS. (QGIS 2.14.2 contains fewer algorithms and v.kernel is missing.)

[image]

In the provider settings, the "GRASS commands" section is used to configure GRASS GIS 6 and the "GRASS GIS 7 commands" section GRASS GIS 7. As far as I know, GRASS GIS 7 doesn't need an msys folder, so if you've never had 6 installed, you won't find any on your computer.

If you haven't installed GRASS GIS 6 on your computer, try deactivating GRASS 6 in your Processing options.

[image]

You can verify if a certain algorithm is included by checking the algorithm description folder in the Processing installation. In an OSGeo4W install that is:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\python\plugins\processing\algs\grass7\description
```

If this folder does not contain a file called v.kernel.rast.txt, we could try if adding it fixes the issue.

Comment: The problem is that I obviously don't have access to all algorithms, besause in the Processing Toolbox I can see next to GRASS GIS 7 commands just 169 commands and not 277 like you can. Then when I have a look in : C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\grass7\description, v.kernel is missing.

Comment: I checked again in QGIS 2.14.2 and you're right, there are only 169 algorithms in the GRASS7 toolbox. I'll update to 2.14.3 to see if that makes a difference. Otherwise you'll need to get the current development version from OSGeo4W.

Comment: I already use the version QGIS 2.14.3..I'll try with the OSGeo4W. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I just downloaded and installed the OSGeo4W Network Installer 64bit. 
In the installer I chose Desktop Express Install and selected those packages to install :QGIS, GRASS GIS, GDAL. GRASS GIS7.0.4 shortage and a OSGeo4W folder appear on my desktop. In the folder OSGeo4W I can find just one shortage : OSGeo4W Shell, which is actually just a black window. My question is where is the program QGIS? I opened C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin but none of the files is the QGIS program.

Comment: Express install won't install the development version. You have to go through advanced install for that. The installer should put icons to start QGIS (and other applications) on the desktop and in the start menu. If this does not happen, run the installer as administrator.

Comment: I did what you described - advanced installing -> Selected packages : QGIS, GRASS GIS, etc. When I opend the program QGIS Desktop 2.14.3 with GRASS 7.0.4., I saw still just 169 algorithms in GRASS QGIS 7 commands (and no v.kernel). And when I go to: C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\grass7\description v.kernel is also missing. The only v.kXY is v.kcv.

Comment: You still installed 2.14. You need to install qgis-dev which will show up as QGIS Desktop 2.15.0 in the start menu.

Comment: I am sorry, I probably do something wrong. I selected advanced installing. And this time I selected to download all the packages but still without the 2.15.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

Even with GRASS 6 deactivated, the missing `msys` folder is a real issue. As a work around, I appeased the `msys` gods by creating the missing (empty) folder in the default `msys` directory. (Since you don't need an `msys` folder to run GRASS 7).

Make sure, like me, if you're running GRASS algorithms through the graphic modeler, to verify that they running through GRASS 7, not 6.

Hope this helps.