# Plugin not available : point sampling tool

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, sampling

I installed the QGIS Standalone Installer Version 2.14 (64bit). I created a map in the program called QGIS Desktop 2.14.3 with GRASS 7.0.4.

I need one tool from Plugin : Point sampling tool. The problem is that I cannot find it anywhere:

[image]

When I check the Plugin settings, I can see that:

[image]

I am using Windows 7 enterprise 64bit.

Why the repository is unavailable? Is that the problem? How can I solve it?

I checked also the proxy:

[image]

Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: Do you have perhaps a solution to that problem? @underdark

Comment: Try to download QGIS LTR 2.8.9, and see if the Long term release can solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't connect to the online repository, download the plugin **manually**:

1. Access the [Point sampling tool plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pointsamplingtool/) from the repository.
2. Click the version required:

   [image: Point sampling tool plugin]
3. Click the **Download** button:

   [image: Download plugin]
4. Extract the **plugin folder** from the zip file and copy/move it to your `.qgis2` directory (e.g. `C:\Users\You\.qgis2\python\plugins`
5. Restart/load QGIS and it should appear as an installed plugin in your `Manage and Install Plugins...` interface.

---

*Note that you can do this for other plugins aswell.*

Comment: OK. No problem till the point 4. I don't have a plugins folder in the .qgis2 folder. When I go here: C:\Users\Me\.qgis2\python, the only folder I can see is: expressions which contains two _init_ files..

Comment: @Janita - Try creating a new folder called "plugins" and insert the plugin folder inside.

Comment: Wow It works ! Thanx a lot, you saved my day.

Comment: @Janita - Most welcome, glad it works :)