# Missing GRASS image processing modules in QGIS 2.14 Processing

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

I am running QGIS 2.14 on debian. I have activated GRASS tools from Processing menu. Some functionality of the GRASS such as image processing modules are missing (i.evapo.pm and ...). how do I get/activate them?

The independent grass installation have the modules. But I am not sure if they work without any modification or how to integrate them into QGIS.

Comment: It is not enough that you have the modules in GRASS; your QGIS processing plugin needs an interface to the GRASS modules too. Seems that they have been integrated between 2.14 and 2.18.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have 2.14 anymore to try, but in QGIS 3.0, the evapo tools are available:

[image]

There certainly were fewer tools back in 2.14 as described in [v.kernel is missing under Processing Toolbox GRASS GIS 7 commands](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197772/v-kernel-is-missing-under-processing-toolbox-grass-gis-7-commands/198041#198041)

Comment: My QGIS 2.14 has only 6 modules under `Grass7 / i.*`, but with different names. QGIS 2.18 has 42 modules. Seems that someone has improved the GRASS adaptation in the meantime.